# How to read MySQL data as JSON

Tags: json, mariadb

I have a database table like this:

[image]

Then I want to read data as json object like this:

```
{
   "date_time":"02102019",
   "ma_vi_tri":
   {
       "1a":222,
       "0a":111,
       "2a":333
   }
 }
```

I use this SQL command like this:

```
MariaDB [mqtt]> SELECT json_object('date_time',date_time,'ma_vi_tri',ma_vi_tri, 'PH', PH) FROM PH where date_time='02102019';
```

[image]

But result output not like I wish.

Comment: I'm not a PHP expert, but I would suggest handling this on the PHP side.

Comment: I'm not PHP expert and MySQL expert, could you give me some example.

Comment: it seems some `CONCAT()` operation will suffice for your problem, but unfortunateIy I cannot see the images you shared.

Comment: which version of MariaDB?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: In mysql you would use json_objectagg() function. However, this is not available in mariadb, so replaced the mysql tag with mariadb, otherwise you can get answers that you cannot use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (be careful with performance problems):

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    '{"date_time": "', `date_time`, '", "ma_vi_tri": ',
    REPLACE(
      GROUP_CONCAT(
        JSON_OBJECT(`ma_vi_tri`, `PH`)
      ),
    '},{',
    ', '
    ),
    '}'
  ) `JSON`
FROM
  `PH`
WHERE
  `date_time` = '02102019'
GROUP BY
  `date_time`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=70f9d1a8b8e2e44922fe0baafa513b06).

Answer (score -1):

You can create a multi dimensional array and use json_encode

Example:

```
$ma_vi_tri_arr['1a'] = "222";
$ma_vi_tri_arr['0a'] = "111";
$ma_vi_tri_arr['2a'] = "333";

$result['date_time'] = "02102019";
$result['ma_vi_tri'] = $ma_vi_tri_arr;

echo(json_encode($result));
```